# How to parsing the input in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to parsing the input in c++!

- 10 will be as n input!
- Words will be string! Note: Some of them has space!
- 10 16 -> 10 will be as n input again! the 16 will be as int e;
- 0 2 to 9 7 should be followed by a and b.

example: all input on the left consider as a and on the right consider as b.

INPUT:

```
10
de
bo
albe
sa fe
bur
mon
btt
nnap
ashin
exan
10 16
0 2
0 1
1 0
2 3
2 0
3 2
4 5
5 4
5 6
6 5
7 8
7 9
8 7
8 9
9 8
9 7
```

```
// Driver code 

int main() { 

  int n,e,a,b;

  cin>>n; 
  string str; 
   int t = n; 
   while (t--) 
   { 
       getline(cin, str); 

       // Keep reading a new line while there is 
       // a blank line 
       while (str.length()==0 ) 
           getline(cin, str); 

     //  cout << str << " : Testing" << endl; 
   } 



   return 0; 
}
```

So far i have above code! but it's not complete! Can anyone help me to write the correct parsing code to read entire input correctly!

Thanks

Comment: *10 16 -> 10 will be as n input again! the 16 will be as int e;
0 2 to 9 7 should be followed by a and b.* ... What?

Comment: 10 16 The 10 should store as int N and 16 will store as int E... ......................................
0 2 The 0 store as A and 2 store as B. It's look like set. {a,b}

Comment: Looks like you have multiple stages. First is a plain old `int` to get how many nodes are in the input. That's what your code's calling `n`. Then you read `n` node names. For each name you're going to need a node. After the `n` names are read, it looks like the remainder of the file is an edge list. Keep reading line by line to the end of the file connecting up the nodes specified by the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this ...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int n,e,a,b;
    cin>>n; 
    string str; 
    int t = n; 
    while (t--)     { 
        getline(cin, str);
        while (str.length()==0 ) 
            getline(cin, str); 
        cout << str << " : Testing" << endl; 
    } 
    int number_count, number;
    cin >> number >> number_count;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_count; i++){
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << a << " - " << b << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer. To salvage it you should explain what what problems of the asker's it solves and how it solves them.